# Data-toggle and data-target are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have been looking around trying different solutions but none have helped me out so far.  My dropdown menu is not working because data-toggle and data-target are not "being recognized" (at least this is why I think it's not working). I can't seem to find the solution so I am hoping someone here can help me out. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
        .box{
            background-color: #d3d3d3;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>


                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 box">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/jumuka/edit?html,output

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `datatoggle="collapse"` you need `data-toggle="collapse"`.